# Guava LoadingCache: How to unit test ListenableFuture within CacheLoader

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, guava

I'm using the [Guava LoadingCache](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) like this:

```
@Inject
private ExecutorService executorService;

private LoadingCache<CacheKey, ResponseEntity<String>> constructCache() {
    return CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(100)
        .expireAfterWrite(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build(
            new CacheLoader<CacheKey, ResponseEntity<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ResponseEntity<String> load(CacheKey cacheKey) throws Exception {
                    return loadResource(cacheKey);
                }
                @Override
                public ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> reload(final CacheKey cacheKey, ResponseEntity<String> old) {
                    ListenableFutureTask<ResponseEntity<String>> task = ListenableFutureTask.create(new Callable<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ResponseEntity<String> call() throws Exception {
                            // this line here!
                            return loadResource(cacheKey);
                        }
                    });
                    executorService.execute(task);
                    return task;
                }
            }
        );
}

private ResponseEntity<String> loadResource(CacheKey cacheKey) {
    // ...
    // external call
    // ...
}
```

I can test every line except one. How do I unit test the line `return loadResource(cacheKey)` within the Runnable task? Right now I'm mocking the executorService in order to make sure the asynchronous refresh is really taking place.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mocking the `ExecutorService`, you can use the [`sameThreadExecutor`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#sameThreadExecutor%28%29) so the task is immediately executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mocking the `ExecutorService`, use an `ArgumentCaptor` to get the `ListenableFutureTask` that was passed. Execute the `call` method on the task and verify that `loadResource` was called.